# Can it ever be possible to program CUDA for Android (Tegra K1)?

Tags: android, cuda

I've been developing for Android for a bit over three years but I want to delve into GPU programming. I've checked out RenderScript but it seems it is tailored more for image processing. I checked out CUDA on Nvidia Tegra K1 and there seems to be a development kit (TADP) available for android developers interested in CUDA. Would appreciate it if someone, who's had experience with the tools, pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is what i do for developing CUDA for Android.

1. Tools:
   TADP for Linux version. My host is ubuntu 12.04, (11.04 can't use this, due to the libc version) There are some sample of CUDA in TADP. you can research how to run and compile first.
2. Device:
   You need a have device which use Tegra K1, BTW, i use Mipad.
3. Books:
   Any books for learning CUDA is OK i think :)